# PropType is defined but prop is never used for arrow function with single argument

Tags: reactjs

Say i have code like this

```
const MessageBody = inner => (
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: inner }} />
);

MessageBody.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Message itself, this can be a html element or plain string
   */
  inner: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.element,
  ]),
};
```

Eslint says 
'inner' PropType is defined but prop is never used lint(react/no-unused-prop-types)

How to fix this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you have named your `props` variable `inner` rather than retrieving it and thus `inner` on your props is never used. What need to do is deconstruct `inner` from your props with:

```
const MessageBody = ({ inner }) => (
....
```

Alternatively, you can fix the name of props and get inner from it with:

```
const MessageBody = props => (
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.inner }} />
);
```